# How to apply custom BidirectionalGraph from QuickGraph to GraphLayout from Graph#?

Tags: c#, graph, quickgraph

Whats wrong?

```
    using QuickGraph;
    using GraphSharp;

     public class State
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }

     public class Event
        {
            public string Name;
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Name;
            }
        }

    BidirectionalGraph<State, TaggedEdge<State, Event>> x =
                    new BidirectionalGraph<State, TaggedEdge<State, Event>>();

    GraphLayout graphLayout = new GraphLayout();
    graphLayout.Graph = x;
```

Error:

Cannot implicitly convert type `QuickGraph.BidirectionalGraph<ChashaGraphSharp.State,QuickGraph.TaggedEdge<ChashaGraphSharp.State,ChashaGraphSharp.Event>>` to `QuickGraph.IBidirectionalGraph<object,QuickGraph.IEdge<object>>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I put the cast, then application gets fault error on start without any information

What's wrong?

Comment: you mean the Graph property of GraphLayout wants a `IBidirectionalGraph<object,QuickGraph.IEdge<object>>` right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your instance of BidirectionGraph using the type IEdge instead of TaggedEdge:

```
BidirectionalGraph<State, IEdge<State, Event>> x =
                new BidirectionalGraph<State, IEdge<State, Event>>();
```

I can't say that I fully understand why this is the case, however the above should work.

**EDIT:** I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671676/casting-generics-and-the-generic-type) that kind of explains why this cast doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a custom graph (IE not a "`BidirectionalGraph<Object, IEdge<Object>`")
You need to use a custom GraphLayout that inherits from "`ContextualGraphLayout`"

Here, instead of using "`GraphLayout`" use "`ContextualGraphLayout<State,Edge<<State>>,BidirectionalGraph<State, Edge<State>>>`".

I strongly advise to create dummy model classes to gain readability.
For instance:

> ```
> public MyVertex : State { }
> public MyEdge : Edge<MyVertex> {
>    public MyEdge (MyVertex source, MyVertex target)
>       : base(source, target) { }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> public MyGraph : BidirectionalGraph<MyVertex, MyEdge> { }
> public MyGraphLayout : ContextualGraphLayout<MyVertex, MyEdge, MyGraph> {
>     public MyGraphLayout () : base() { }
>
>     public MyGraphLayout (bool allowParallelEdges)
>         : base(allowParallelEdges) { }
>
>     public MyGraphLayout (bool allowParallelEdges, int vertexCapacity)
>         : base(allowParallelEdges, vertexCapacity) { }
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Yes

But TaggedEdge does not implement  IEdge interface
How to use custom TaggedEdge?

Comment: It is inherited from Edge which implements IEdge. You can create a new class which will implement both IEdge and ITagged.